# How do insert row into Child Table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I'm fairly new to entity framework and patterns.  How would I insert data into a child table?

I inserted the information into the parent table.  Do I have to return the identity of the row and then issue another insert?

User Table  and User Role.

I've been trying to find a solution for a day now, but I think its because I'm searching the wrong results.  My structure is set up using Unit of Work/Repository Pattern.

Any help would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the Parent object. Add the child record to it's navigation property.

something like this

```
int orderId=33;

var parent=dbContext.Orders.Where(x=>x.Id==orderId);

parent.Details.Add(new OrderDetail{ Quantity=4, ItemId=37});
parent.Details.Add(new OrderDetail{ Quantity=2, ItemId=48});

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Assuming Order is your Master entity and Detail is your child entity and dbContext is your DBContext class object.

**EDIT :** If you are adding it together,

```
Order parent=new Order { CustomerId=35, Discount=43.63 };
parent.Details.Add(new OrderDetail{ Quantity=4, ItemId=37});
parent.Details.Add(new OrderDetail{ Quantity=2, ItemId=48});

dbContext.Orders.Add(parent);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Is this the only way to do it?  Grab the ID and then run another SaveChanges()?  I was trying to see if there was another way to do this since its going to run SaveChanges() twice.

Comment: Yes, but I mean when I add Order in and then I added OrderDetails in.  This would result in me running it twice when I'm adding the order and i need to add the orderdetail right after.

Comment: @AllenTongI If you are adding it together, You can do it once. see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks!  This seems to work, I just need to sort my database issues now